# I don't know who my manager is

Tags: resignation, manager

I currently work in an airport as a sales assistant, and as you know, there is a lot of security which unfortunately splits me apart from any contact with my manager (due to the fact I work in arrivals and they are based in depatures) because of this I have no idea who my manager is or what his/her name is however I need to write a resignation letter addressing him/her.

Can any one advise me what I can do :)?

Thank you!

Comment: Someone hired you: ask them. Someone pays you: ask them. Unless you work 100% alone you have co-workers: ask them. Someone sets up shift, work hours, opens/closes, does the accounting, checks the inventory: asl them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HR is your definitive source of information for this question and all others related to the company's organizational chart. If you don't know who to contact in HR, start with the person who sent you your employment contract when you first started working there, or the person you notify when you need to take a sick day or vacation time.